# Yeoman (bower,grunt) - 'SockJS' is not defined

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, yeoman, bower, sockjs

I am trying to manage a javascript frontend application with yeoman. I don't have any yeoman experience. While running grunt command I am getting this error:

```
Running "jshint:all" (jshint) task
Linting app/scripts/services/stopmOverSockJs.js ...ERROR
[L7:C26] W117: 'SockJS' is not defined.
        var socket = new SockJS(url);
```

I have defined sock js dependency in bower.json :

```
{
  "name": "web",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
      "sockjs": "~0.3.4",
      "angular": "~1.0.7",
...
```

and bower install command runs without problems and it downloads all dependencies including sockjs.

This is the file that the grunt command complains about :

```
'use strict';

angular.module('webApp').factory('sockJsHelper', function($rootScope) {

    function Handler(url) {
        var socket = new SockJS(url); //it complains about this line
....
```

What do I have to do in order to make SockJS recognized?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JSHint thinks SockJS is undefined because it cannot find it in your script; even if you have loaded it in through the browser! To fix this behaviour, add this to the JSHint config in your Gruntfile:

```
jshint: {
    options: {
        // all of your other options...
        predef: ['SockJS']
    },
    files : ['path/to/main.js']
},
```